# Parameter routing and condition dont work on production mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a simple routing like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'scenario',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/scenarios/scenario/scenario.module').then( m => m.ScenarioPageModule)
  }
 ]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then in app.component.ts

```
    export class AppComponent  {
    
    {
        this.initializeApp();
    }
    
      initializeApp() {
    
            //Get urlParameter
            this.getParameter()
    
              if(this.source == "kiosk"){
    
               //go to route
               this.navController.navigateRoot('scenario');
             }
           }


getParameter() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
      let splitURL = document.URL.split("?");
      let splitParams = splitURL[1].split("&");
      let i: any;
      for (i in splitParams){
        let singleURLParam = splitParams[i].split('=');
        console.log(singleURLParam[1])
        if (singleURLParam[0] == "utm_source"){
          this.source = singleURLParam[1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I read the URL parameter and if it equals "Kiosk" it redirects to scenario page. So if I run the project on localhost and try with this URL: `http://localhost:8100/scenario/?utm_source=kiosk` it works, it redirects to scenario and do everything well.

The problem starts when I publish on production, the URL I tried is: `myapp.company.com/scenario/?utm_source=kiosk` it just return 404 - file directory not found

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: How is your production server rouring configured? What server do you use? Looks very probably unrelated to your Angular app code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular web server acts as a reverse proxy which behaves like this:

- If the incoming requests matches a asset file (CSS, JS, image, ...), serve it
- Otherwise, serve the `index.html` file in order to execute the JavaScript code in the browser

When the `index.html` is being served and the JavaScript executes, the current URL is treated like an Angular route and the corresponding layout/component is displayed.

Wherever you are trying to deploy, it should have URL rewriting abilities and you should configure it in order to mimic Angular's development server behavior.

Here are some useful resources for the three most popular web servers:

- [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)
- [IIS blog article](https://medium.com/the-tech-masters/publish-angular-app-into-iis-2f00137ba189)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what server is used, I host on [smarterasp](https://www.smarterasp.net/hosting_plans), I just do an ionic build and publish www folder

Comment: I don't know that hosting service, all I can say is that if it does not allow URL rewriting, then an initial navigation to an Angular app won't work

Comment: I asked to support and they told me it is supported already, but I do not understand what config, should I do to achieve it, it's an IIS server

Comment: Then you have to edit `web.xml` I hope your hosting service allows you to edit it. This might help you: https://medium.com/the-tech-masters/publish-angular-app-into-iis-2f00137ba189

Comment: Yes, I added web.config with rewrite rule and it works! Thanks

Comment: Glad to know that you made it. I'm adding that link to my answer.